# Is dotted decimal notation in base 256 or 10?

Tags: networking, ip

IP V4 address is a 32 bits address.

In dotted decimal notation we divide IP Address in 4 parts and write the value of each octet.

```
for example:  binary----> 10000000 00000001 00000001 00000001

              base 10----> 1*(2^31+2^16+2^8+2^0)

              base 256----> 128       1        1        1
```

Can i say? "it is not true that people say dotted decimal notation is in base 10"

Additional information for my question:

when i want to convert base 2 to 16 i should start from right to left and because 2^4=16 make groups in 4 members and write the value

```
binary   1000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0001 0000 0001
hex       8      0    0    0    0    1    0   1
```

I think in dotted decimal notation we create 4 groups by 8 members for each group , because 2^8=256 and we dont have enough digits for base 256 and we write the value of each group in base 10, isn't it?

Comment: If it was in "base 256", then it'd have 256 different digits. If it only has 10 digits – `0123456789` – then it's base-10.

Comment: Please see my additional information for my question:

Comment: I am sorry for my English

Comment: @grawity It does have 256 different digits. Imagine if you were going to express the IP address 127.0.0.1 in base 256. How would you do it? First, you'd somehow write the number 127, then some separator, then the number 0, then some separator, then the number 0, then some separator, then the number 1 somehow. Well, that's exactly what "127.0.0.1" is. So how can that not be expressing the address in base 256?!

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: This is not how a "base" is defined in the first place, _that's_ how. "127" is a number, but it's not a digit, it's just a group of base-10 digits.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, your logic only works when discussing dotted-decimal notation; it does not make Base256 a legitimate means for expressing numbers based on our species current use of characters. no reason we couldn't add new characters to work in base256, but we don't have them today.

Comment: @FrankThomas His question is about dotted decimal notation, which takes the IP address in base 256 and expresses each digit in base 10. The crux of a base is how you break an arbitrarily large number into groups with a limited size, not how you represent the number in each group. Base 10 is about having 9 or fewer units, 9 or fewer tens, and so on.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's essentially a mathematics question, even if in a computer and/or TCP/IP context.

Comment: Wikipedia indicates, that, "A common use of dot-decimal notation is in information technology where it is a method of writing numbers in octet-grouped base-10 (decimal) numbers separated by dots (full stops).".  Any event, instead of calling it base 256, call it `dotted-quad notation` everyone with networking experience will know what you mean.

Comment: It is also notable, that in the context of TCP/IP, an IP address is treated as bytes in binary, and does not at any point treat the IP address as a single numerical value. The RFCs governing TCP/IP make this very very very clear in their description of routeing, subnet masking, supernetting/route aggregation, etc.

Comment: @FrankThomas is rights. It's actually a base-2 number, a combination of 4 bytes of information, which is also why it is called an "octet", which is a set of 8. The ACTUAL number that the computer is using in an IP address is in THIS format: 00000000.00000000.00000000.00000000 (That's 0.0.0.0). The reason it maxes at 256 per octet is because the maximum value for that in binary is 11111111.11111111.11111111.11111111 which is 256.256.256.256.

Answer (score 4):

Dotted decimal notation uses both base 256 and base 10. The IP address is expressed in base 256. But lacking 256 convenient symbols to use, each digit of the base 256 IP address is expressed as its value in base 10.

Something is expressed in base ten if it is divided into no more than nine units, then no more than nine tens, no more than nine hundreds, and so on. Here, the IP address is divided into no more than 255 units, no more than 255 65,536's, no more than 255 256^2, and so on. So it is expressed in base 256.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55512/discussion-on-answer-by-david-schwartz-is-dotted-decimal-notation-in-base-256-or).

Answer (score 3):

The `Decimal` in Dotted-Decimal indicates base10. In fact, thats what `Decimal` literally means (a thing in increments of "deci" or "10")

> Decimal
>
> Adjective
>
> 1. pertaining to tenths or to the number 10.
> 2. proceeding by tens: a decimal system.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/decimal

Its also important to note that IP addresses are not a single number when processed, but 4 bytes of binary, that are evaluated in parts, not in a whole, so while you could add all 4 bytes together into a number with a range of 0-4.1 billion, That is never how it is actually used by the TCP/IP stack.

For instance in [RFC 791](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791), each Octet's high order bits are evaluated in certian patterns including those with a 0 at the beginning. If you are looking at bytes, its perfectly reasonable that a byte might begin with a 0 bit, but for Numbers, Either No numbers start with zero, or All of them do, depending on how you want to thing about it.
So put simply, an IP address is not a number, it is a set of numbers that work Together, in much the same way Latitude and Longitude do.

Comment: why in the book "Data Communications and Networking by Behrouz A.Forouzan, 5th Edition" it is base 256?

Comment: the book is saying that it is in base 256 but we write each group in decimal

Comment: I can't speak to what a specific author said without more context, but in point of fact, there aren't enough glyphs in the latin alphabet for 256 individual values within that base.

Comment: It doesn't make sense for it to be "in base 256". Each _group_ of numbers (octet) can have 256 different values, from 0 to 255, but that's generally _not_ what "base" means...

Comment: you may be missing that number bases (except binary) are meaningless. its like translating english to spanish and vice versa. The word for rice may be differant, but the meaning of them both is the same, and the rice is just rice no matter what you call it. number bases allow us to "Express" or Say numbers. They don't change what they are. Binary is differant because our data is stored and processed as on/off combinations in hardware, so in computing it is the only base with a basis in physical reality.

Comment: @grawity That's precisely what "base" means. To express a number in base 10, you divide it by 10 repeatedly and then represent each of those numbers somehow. Here, the IP address is divided by 256 repeatedly and then each of those numbers is expressed somehow. How those numbers are expressed is a different question from how the outer number, the IP address in this case, is expressed. (Here, the digits of the base 256 number are expressed in base 10. But that's a different question from how the IP address is expressed.)